# i tried to style my navbar but it is not working well and i don't know why?

Tags: html, css

i am trying to make an unordered list in the navbar and make anchors inline but the style doesn't apply. the below style of stylish navbar not working . but it applies when i try to change background color

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <nav class="stylishnavbar">
            <h1 class="logo">portfolio</h1>
            <ul>
                <li ><a href="#"></a>home </li>
                <li ><a href="#"></a> about</li>
                <li ><a href="#"></a>services </li>
                <li ><a href="#"></a> skills</li>
                <li ><a href="#"></a>contact </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

css style

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.logo{
    padding: 5px;
}
.header{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image:url(./img/code.jpg) ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
.stylishnavbar{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: You never applied any declerations that would make a list align horizontally. The flexbox needs to be added to the ul to make the anchors "inline"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Flex only applies to the immediate children. Right now, it's just applying to the h1 and ul.

Add

```
.stylishnavbar > ul { display: flex; }
```

To apply flex to your list.

Comment: while thsi answer the question it shoud have not been answered. He applied the flexbox to the wrong element which is equivalent to a typo-caused issue and as such should haven been flaggend and close as `Not reproducible or caused by typos`. Also it could have been commented instead!

Comment: Shouldn't answers be in answers, and questions or comments about the question be in comments?

Comment: I understand why you think that way. However poor questions or questiosn with no value to SO should not be answered btu flagged to move it faster out of the search list. Typo caused issue such as this have no value to the community and need to be removed. Answering or even upvoting causes the automatic removal system/queue to take longer. Once the question is removed, all gained reputation through upvotes or checked as an answer will be gone, so there is no advantage in answerign typo caused questions.

Answer (score -1):

I hope this code will solve your problem...

```css
*{
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .logo {
            padding: 5px;
        }

        .header {
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100%;
           
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
        }

        .stylishnavbar {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
        }
        nav.stylishnavbar ul {
            display: flex;
            list-style: none;
       }
       nav.stylishnavbar ul li{
             margin-right: 30px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css"
        integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <nav class="stylishnavbar">
            <h1 class="logo">portfolio</h1>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"></a>home </li>
                <li><a href="#"></a> about</li>
                <li><a href="#"></a>services </li>
                <li><a href="#"></a> skills</li>
                <li><a href="#"></a>contact </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).